# How to manage data between listview and listview detail screen?

Tags: android, listview

I am using a listview with a custom adapter. In my listview I am showing feeds, there is a option to like or dislike the post. On clicking listview item I am simply sending the arraylist and position in the DetailScreenActivity class. In the detail screen there is also the option to like or dislike the post.

Now suppose if the user likes the post in the detail screen and comes back, he still gets the post unliked in listview. May I know how could I manage this?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume of listView screen. This will refresh the list.

Comment: the arraylist on the listview screen is same, its not changed, nothing will change

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you are passing the array list with clicked position, now when user presses back then you have to pass your updated arraylist and update the adapter with  this arraylist.

Comment: for this I have to finish current activity and start new and vice versa, n then i have to send index also, is sending arraylist and getting back is right approach?

Comment: you start your detail activity with startActivityForResult and when you want to go back just set the updated arraylist in setresult And finish the current activity. And again on list activity you have to handle onActivityResult where you can get the updated list data and notify your listview.